# c++ webserver not sending data correctly

Tags: c++, winsock

I wanted to build a super simple web server, which should at first only be transmitting a string, no matter what the requested address was, in this case "Hello Web".

I modified the code from here: https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/01/17/socket-cc-windows/.
Currently it tells me that there was an HTTP response error in chrome when I go to my server on 127.0.0.1:5555.

Server Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
 
    SOCKET server, client;
 
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr, clientAddr;
 
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(5555);
 
    bind(server, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    listen(server, 0);
 
    cout << "Listening for incoming connections..." << endl;
 
    char buffer[1024];
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    if((client = accept(server, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
        recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        cout << "Client says: " << string(buffer) << endl;

        string response = "Hello Web\r\n";
        send(client, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
        cout << "msg send: " << response << endl;
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
 
        closesocket(client);
        cout << "Client disconnected." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Hello Web\r\n` isn't a valid HTTP response.

Comment: thanks... didn't thought, it would be that simple.

Comment: The 200 has to come from somewhere, and content-length, .... Have you ever looked at a HTTP GET and its response -try peeking at what your browser sends/receives by using e.g. Telerik Fiddler (Windows) or mitm (Linux).

Answer (score 0):

```
    recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    cout << "Client says: " << string(buffer) << endl;
```

You ignore the return value of `recv`. How are you expecting the next line of code to know how many bytes of data to output?

Also, there's no guarantee that this single call to `recv` will get the whole query. It may get only a tiny piece of the header.

```
    string response = "Hello Web\r\n";
    send(client, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
```

This probably isn't a valid HTTP response, but there's no way we can be sure. Your code doesn't look at the query to see, for example, what version it is. This might be a valid HTTP 0.9 response, but it's certainly not a valid HTTP 1.0 response.